# setState nested object failed with spread operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I follow this example

[react set state in for nested state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/react-set-state-in-for-nested-state)

to set nested state in react. What's wrong with below code? I want e.target.name as the property of the object.

```
onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        input: {...this.state.input, e.target.name: e.target.value}
    })
  }
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/qqwokzzym9

Comment: use bracket notation for computed property name: `[e.target.name]: ....`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: your codesandbox is broken. use inline snippets and fix your code

Comment: check working code [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rw550n33lm)